# 404 error after calling j_security_check

Tags: jsf, tomcat7

The weirdest thing happening in my web application. Here is the `<security-constraint>` section of web.xml:

```
   <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Non-secure resources</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/js/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/theme/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/login.jsp</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/logout.faces</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Secure resources</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/fragments/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>AllAuthenticated</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>map</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/loginError.jsp</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>AllAuthenticated</role-name>
    </security-role>
```

When the user accesses the the application through `http://<host-name>/<context-path>/`, then the user is forwarded to login page and after successful login everything is fine. But if the user accesses the application through `http://<host-name>/<context-path>/login.jsp`, after successful log in, user gets a 404 error message and the URL in the browser is `http://<host-name>/<context-path>/j_security_check`.

Anybody knows why this is happening and how I can prevent it?

Comment: Please add the login.jsp

Answer (score 0):

You have to add these lines to your web.xml  :

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
<dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add this element in the web.xml.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/j_security_check</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```